# Can test projects be excluded from the Startup Project selector in Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net-core, mstest, visual-studio-2022

When a test project is added to a solution containing a console or web application project, the test project appears in the Startup Project dropdown menu. The test project can be selected as the startup project by default when Visual Studio is first opened. If there are many test projects, it becomes difficult to find and select the actual intended startup project.

I would like to configure the projects or solution so that test projects don't appear in the Startup Project menu.

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 and .NET 6. My test projects use MSTest. Here's an example created using the ASP.NET Core Web API, MSTest Test Project, and Class Library templates. Notice how `WebApplication` and `TestProject` both appear in the Startup Project selector, but `ClassLibrary` does not.

[image: The Solution Explorer, showing a solution named WebApplication containing an ASP.NET project named WebApplication, a test project named TestProject, and a class library project named ClassLibrary.]

[image: The Startup Project dropdown menu, which lists both WebApplication and TestProject.]

`WebApplication.csproj`:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

`TestProject.csproj`:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.3.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="2.2.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="2.2.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.1.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

`ClassLibrary.csproj`:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

`WebApplication.sln`:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio Version 17
VisualStudioVersion = 17.5.33424.131
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "WebApplication", "WebApplication\WebApplication.csproj", "{01F0A111-DEF7-412E-A9C5-DAA00C1FF909}"
EndProject
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "TestProject", "TestProject\TestProject.csproj", "{DB4D909F-B896-4B66-994A-B42C071DB6F1}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "ClassLibrary", "ClassLibrary\ClassLibrary.csproj", "{DA28A343-376E-45AA-BD06-80DA4896AA1F}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {01F0A111-DEF7-412E-A9C5-DAA00C1FF909}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {01F0A111-DEF7-412E-A9C5-DAA00C1FF909}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {01F0A111-DEF7-412E-A9C5-DAA00C1FF909}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {01F0A111-DEF7-412E-A9C5-DAA00C1FF909}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {DB4D909F-B896-4B66-994A-B42C071DB6F1}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {DB4D909F-B896-4B66-994A-B42C071DB6F1}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {DB4D909F-B896-4B66-994A-B42C071DB6F1}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {DB4D909F-B896-4B66-994A-B42C071DB6F1}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {DA28A343-376E-45AA-BD06-80DA4896AA1F}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {DA28A343-376E-45AA-BD06-80DA4896AA1F}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {DA28A343-376E-45AA-BD06-80DA4896AA1F}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {DA28A343-376E-45AA-BD06-80DA4896AA1F}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {2210AA20-D0E8-418D-9796-B47D837831A1}
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

The test projects appear to have an Output Type of Console Application, so I've tried changing it to Class Library. When I make this change in the project's Properties view in Visual Studio, the selection is immediately changed back to Console Application. This does add `<OutputType>Library</OutputType>` to the project file, but the project still appears in the Startup Project dropdown.

Comment: No , I don't think we have such option in visual studio. It displays all the projects

Comment: @amitagarwal, thanks for your response. It does not display all of the projects. Projects with an output type of Class Library are not included.

Comment: I can see the Class Library as well in this list.

Comment: All projects in the solution are in the drop-down including class library projects.

Comment: I've edited the question to include a class library project. I'm not seeing it in the dropdown.

Comment: If you create a blazor webassembly project by selecting Asp.Net Core Hosted, you can get the same [situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQ8YB.png). Which the library will not be shown in the dropdown.